# How to draw rects inside QPdfView?

Tags: c++, qt, pdf, qt5

I've created a simple widget, that just display the PDF document with QT 5.15 and QPdfView class.
I need to highlight the words with rects in PDF document. I can get the coordinates of some words with QPdfSearchModel class. That is example of what i want to create

[image: EXAMPLE]

I can't find the way of drawing rects inside QPdfView widget

What I tried to do is:

```
class QPdfViewCustom : public QPdfView
{
    public:
        explicit QPdfViewCustom(QWidget* parent = nullptr):QPdfView(parent){};
    protected:
        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) override
        {
            QPdfView::paintEvent(event);
            QPainter painter(this->viewport());
            painter.drawRect(0,0,100,100);          

        }

};
```

But this code draw right on viewport, so, when i scroll the PDF document this rect always stay on the same position:

[image: MY CODE DRAW THIS]

So, my question is, how to draw rects inside QPdfView and make them scrollable like in existed PDFViewers.
This is the documentation of QT Pdf module https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qtpdf-module.html
QPdfView class inherits from QAbstractScrollArea

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Qt docs of [`QAbstractScrollArea`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qabstractscrollarea.html#details), you should draw the contents taking the scroll positions into account:

> Draw the contents of the area in the viewport according to the values of the scroll bars.

`QScrollArea` is able to perform this mapping for you, but `QPdfView` isn't derived from `QScrollArea`.